# How to sorting by date string with mat-sort-header?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a case table constructed with `angular.material` and I need to add sorting by date. But my date is a `string` type, and so sorting incorrectly. How to overriding default `mat-sort-header` behavior. And it's possible?

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

        <!-- Reg Date Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="regDate">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Reg Date </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.regDate}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
</div>
```

And on TS side:

```
sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatSort)
set appBacon(sort : MatSort) {
    this.sort = sort;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is the solution:- 
Pass Date object in sortingDataAccessor function which will make sure date objects will get sorted correctly.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
    case 'fromDate': return new Date(item.fromDate);
    default: return item[property];
  }
};
```

MatTableDataSource has sortingDataAccessor which we can customize as per our need.

Comment: This worked PERFECTLY!  Please note:  Add this snippet of code to a method like ngAfterViewInit or something.

Comment: Here is some documentation for his answer. https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatHeaderRow

Comment: Has anyone checked this with Angular7 ? Is yes then please let me know

Comment: This works with angular 7 but only the first row is not sorted for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Sagar - can confirm it works with ng8.

Comment: `sortingDataAccessor` should return `string | number` and you're returning `Date`

Comment: In my case it wasn't ordering correctly so I used moment: `return moment(item[property], "DD/MM/YYYY").unix();`

Answer (score 32):

I'm expanding on Sagar Kharche answer. You need to override the sortingDataAccessor on MatTableDataSource.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
     case 'fromDate': return new Date(item.fromDate);
     default: return item[property];
  }
};
```

'item' is the object ObjectName in 'dataSource: MatTableDataSource< ObjectName>'

'property' is the matColumnDef="startDate" attribute coming in.

So for example you might have an object as follows:

```
export interface IPersonInfo {
    name: string,
    position: string,
    startDate: string,
    salary: string
}
```

Your date table element would look like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="startDate">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Start Date </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.startDate}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

So when you click on the header to sort 'Start Date', all the objects under the startDate column get passed in one by one into the 'item' value, while the 'startDate' in matColumnDef="startDate" is passed in as the 'property' value in the sortingDataAccessor function.

So with the sortingDataAccessor function you could override every single column.

```
this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
  switch (property) {
     case 'name': return item.name;
     case 'position': return item.position;
     case 'startDate': return item.startDate;
     case 'salary': return item.salary;
     default: return item[property];
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

You need to provide a a function to `MatTableDataSource.sortData` field.

You can find the signature and default implementation [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/table/table-data-source.ts)

For e.g:

```
customSortData(data: T[], sort: MatSort): T[] {
 // sort.active will tell you if sort is active and for which headerid
 // sort.direction will tell u if sort is 'asc' or not
return data.sort((a, b) => {// Ur implementation});
}
```

It is always recommended to use a type for a table, rather than using array of any type. You can define your interface for the same.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: yes this very interesting, thank you. Wanted to clarify are you mean for injection my logic for sorting I must `dataSource.sortData = customSortData` (`sortData` is a field which contain function). True I understand

Answer (score 3):

I want to add to Sagar Kharche's answer.

sortingDataAccessor only returns 'string | number'. So if you just return a Date object, you get this error:

> string | number | Date' is not assignable to type '(data: Inventory, sortHeaderId: string) => string | number'.

So I did this instead:

```
  this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
    switch(property) {
      case 'dateReceived': return new Date(item.dateReceived).getTime();
      case 'dateOpened': return new Date(item.dateOpened).getTime();
      default: return item[property as keyof Inventory] as string;
    }
  }
```

Where we getTime() for our dates so it returns a number, and return a string for all other properties as default. I also added `item[property as keyof Inventory] as string` on the default case to fix this error:

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Inventory'.

I also followed this blog: https://www.angularjswiki.com/material/mat-table-sort/